# How to avoid deadlocks when generating consecutive ticket numbers?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, deadlock

I have implemented a ticketing system where when you join an event and placed an order depending on the quantity, a *n* of entries will be generated. Example: you place an order with 10 quantity, a 10 ticket number would be generated. The rule is, ticket number starts at 1 and would increment by 1 every time it is generated. The ticket number always starts with 1 on each event and each orders can have multiple entries.

| event_id | ticket_no | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 |

So currently, in order to generate a ticket no. for each event. I used a MySQL trigger to increment its value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER number_generator BEFORE INSERT ON entries
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.ticket_no = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ticket_no), 0) + 1 FROM entries WHERE event_id = NEW.event_id);
END;
```

Here is a sample raw query of how I trigger ticket no. generation

```
insert into
  `entries` (`order_id`, `event_id`, `ticket_no`)
values
  (123, 1, 1),
  (123, 1, 1),
  (123, 1, 1),
  ...
```

The problem: When multiple users place an order at the same time, the system would randomly throw a deadlock exception:

> Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

In my old implementation, which uses MyISAM tables
with auto increment on second column, I wouldn't encounter this issue, and the ticket number generation was faster. How can I resolve the deadlock and achieve MyIsam speed in inserting, but with InnoDB?

---

Orders Table Definition

```
  CREATE TABLE `orders` (
      `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
      `event_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL, 
      `first_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `last_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `owning_event` (`event_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Entries Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `event_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ticket_no` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`,`ticket_no`),
  KEY `entries_event_id_index` (`event_id`),
  KEY `entries_order_id_index` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `entries_order_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `entries_event_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Old entries Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE entries_old (
    event_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ticket_no MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id, ticket_no)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you know why `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ticket_no), 0) + 1 FROM entries` is not the right way to emulate a sequence; it's slow and prone to lock contention and race conditions. You'll have to rethink your approach.

Firstly, the rule that says "ticket number starts at 1 and would increment by 1 every time it is generated" seems arbitrary. You can just as well uniquely identify tickets by a regular `auto_increment` column.

If for some reason you insist on implementing this rule, you might choose to maintain the "next ticket number" pseudo-sequence as a column in the `events` table, but that won't guarantee a gapless sequence either.

Comment: I can't use the `auto_increment` since the ticket no should restart a 1 on new events.

Comment: I don't see why this is the case, as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: And you must use InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Use InnoDB; Use transactions; use `FOR UPDATE`.

Give this a try...  Have another table.  Based on your example, it would have

```
event_id  order_id  tkt_start  tkt_ct
1         1         1          2
1         2         3          1
1         3         4          1
1         6         5          1
2         4         1          1
2         5         2          1

PRIMARY KEY(event_id, tkt_start)
```

Use one transaction to insert *one* row into this table.  It will involve a `MAX` and other messy stuff.  But, by inserting only one row, it will be *less* likely to be deadlocked.  Possibly it can be a single statement.

You *must* write code to check for errors and restart the transaction if it was a victim of a deadlock.

Then, in a separate transaction build the multiple rows in your table.  This is unlikely to block because these insert(s) are unlikely to conflict with other actions.

You must *not* have a transaction that spans the time where a user is checking with their spouse to see if the tickets will be OK.  If you need to "reserve" tickets that might later get canceled, a different locking mechanism is needed than just a single InnoDB transaction.

If you need a "reserve / chat / confirm" sequence, then you must be willing to lose the consecutive nature of ticket numbers.  (This is required when selling *seats*; I don't understand your need for no-gaps in ticket numbers.)

Answer (score -1):

### Serialize your requests to avoid deadlocks

```
SELECT events.id FROM event WHERE events.id = :eventId FOR UPDATE
```

The above will cause every other person attempting to place an order for a given event to wait while this first thread finishes. That will prevent deadlocks, but doesn't help on speed, and will potentially slow it, as only one thread can operate at a time.

### Calculate ticket numbers in your app

So, to make up for potential speed loss, stop making the MySQL do all the work for computing the ticket numbers. You have a good index, but it still takes more time than whatever is the equivalent of your application language's `$ticketNumber++`. Since requests are serialized you don't have to worry about having duplicate values generated.

```
SELECT MAX(entries.ticket_no) FROM entries WHERE entries.event_id = :eventId
```

Take the result from this query, and then compile the SQL statement in a loop in your application until you build a string that looks like

```
insert into
  `entries` (`order_id`, `event_id`, `ticket_no`)
values
  (123, 1, 5),
  (123, 1, 6),
  (123, 1, 7),
  ...
```

(In this example, the highest `ticket_no` was 4, from the `MAX` query above.)

Then you just have one insert, it should execute very quickly because there is no longer a trigger running for each row, and when you commit the transaction then the lock from the `FOR UPDATE` query is released and the next thread (if any) can execute.

This should be quite fast, and satisfy your business rule of each event having ticket numbers ranging from 1 to [max number of tickets].